# Reorder bars of ggplot2 plot based on the value of a level of a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data frame `df` with 46 rows and 3 columns.

I am trying to create a plot of the value of the `youth_activity_rc` variables by `program_ID` variables, like this code / plot . . .

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = program_name, y = total_minutes_p, group = youth_activity_rc, fill = youth_activity_rc)) +
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image: geom_col figure]

. . . but with the `program_ID` variables reordered on the basis of the value of `Not Focused` factor level of the `youth_activity_rc` variable:

There are a number of questions demonstrating how to do this on the basis of a single variable (i.e., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288761/reordering-columns-by-y-value-in-r)), but none that I could find doing so on the basis of a value associated with the level of a factor (`Not Focused` in this case); it seems simple, but at least based on solutions recommended in other answers (i.e., using `stats::reorder()` or `dplyr::arrange()`), it is not.

The data is here:

```
df <- structure(list(program_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1", "2", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), youth_activity_rc = structure(c(2L, 
6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Not Focused", 
"Basic Skills Activity", "Program Staff Led", "Field Trip Speaker", 
"Lab Activity", "Creating Product"), class = "factor"), total_minutes_p = c(0.248, 
0.116, 0.075, 0.458, 0.103, 0.466, 0.015, 0.202, 0.317, 0.248, 
0.263, 0.006, 0.372, 0.111, 0.183, 0.172, 0.088, 0.048, 0.305, 
0.203, 0.157, 0.066, 0.079, 0.592, 0.106, 0.128, 0.423, 0.423, 
0.026, 0.176, 0.233, 0.125, 0.426, 0.04, 0.164, 0.188, 0.046, 
0.007, 0.524, 0.072, 0.163, 0.112, 0.013, 0.021, 0.567, 0.124
)), .Names = c("program_ID", "youth_activity_rc", "total_minutes_p"
), row.names = c(NA, -46L), vars = "program_ID", labels = structure(list(
    program_ID = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), .Names = "program_ID", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame", vars = "program_ID", drop = TRUE), indices = list(
    0:4, 5:8, 9:13, 14:19, 20:24, 25:28, 29:33, 34:39, 40:45), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(5L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L), biggest_group_size = 6L, class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering your dataset by `youth_activity_rc` and `total_minutes_p` and then using `fct_inorder` from package *forcats* prior to plotting is one option.

`fct_inorder` sets the levels of the factor in the order they appear in the dataset, which is why ordering the dataset to get the levels of `program_ID` in the desired order is needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df2 = df %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(youth_activity_rc, total_minutes_p) %>%
    mutate(program_ID = fct_inorder(program_ID) )
```

And the plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = program_ID, y = total_minutes_p, 
             group = youth_activity_rc, 
             fill = youth_activity_rc)) +
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Use `fct_relevel` while `arrange`ing to set the level of the factor you want to base the order on as the first level.  For example, if you wanted a graph ordered by `total_minutes_p` in "Creating Product" instead of "Not Focused":

```
df2 = df %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(fct_relevel(youth_activity_rc, "Creating Product"), total_minutes_p) %>%
    mutate(program_ID = fct_inorder(program_ID) )
```

[image]

Comment: Any straightforward way to do this if `Not Focused` didn't happen to be the first level of `youth_activity_rc`, other than setting it to the first level?

Comment: Not that I know of, but that can be done within `arrange` if you don't want to change the levels of your ordering factor permanently.  See edit.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to aosmith, but not using forcats/dplyr for the data manipulation. You can get the order *within* the subset you want and then refactor your data to have the levels in that order. Something like:

```
levs <- df[which(df$youth_activity_rc == "Not Focused"), ] #Get the "Not focused" group
order <- order(levs[,"total_minutes_p"]) #Order within your selected group

df$program_ID_2 <- factor(df$program_ID, levels = levs[order, "program_ID"])

ggplot(df, aes(x = program_ID_2, y = total_minutes_p, 
                group = youth_activity_rc, 
                fill = youth_activity_rc)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Note I created a new variable called `program_ID_2` but you don't have to